# Open-XML document has no content

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

I am trying to create the most simple docx file using OpenXML, the file is correctly generated, open correctly, but has no content. My PC does not have Microsoft Office installed.

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(filePath, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
            {
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.AddMainDocumentPart();
                mainPart.Document = new Document(
                    new Body(
                        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Paragraph(
                            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Run(
                                new Text("Hello World!!!!!")))));
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-create-a-word-processing-document-by-providing-a-file-name).
You using `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing` namespace instead of `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing`.
Change `usings` to correct one:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(filePath, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.AddMainDocumentPart();
    mainPart.Document = new Document(
      new Body(
        new Paragraph(
          new Run(
            new Text("Hello World!!!!!")))));
}
```

Comment: How did you figure out the namespaces were wrong? I do not see them in the question?

Comment: @Durga Prasad, look at `...(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Paragraph(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Run(...)` part.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.